# Rails, Devise: DoubleRenderError in FailureApp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to configure Devise so that whenever a User which account has not been confirmed logs in, he gets redirected to the `new_confirmation_path`.
This is what I've got so far:

*lib/custom_failure.rb*

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
    def redirect_url
        if warden_message == :unconfirmed
            redirect_to new_user_confirmation_path(q: "unconfirmed")
        else
            super
        end
    end
    def respond
        if http_auth?
            http_auth
        else
            redirect
        end
    end
end
```

*config/application.rb*

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

*config/initializers/devise.rb*

```
config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
end
```

Unfortunately I get the following error, whenever a User tries to log in:

> AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Users::SessionsController#create
>   Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".
>   Error in lib/custom_failure.rb (around line #15)

I followed this [Devise Wiki Page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by the error, you are performing a **double render** (render or redirect). I guess that's it's directly related to your `redirect_url` method.

Looking on the [devise's wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated), there's no need to perform a redirect while override the `redirect_url` method. Also, by checking [devise's failure code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/lib/devise/failure_app.rb#L86), at the end of the failed request, your application is doing this:

```
redirect_to(redirect_url)
# Which is equal to
redirect_to(redirect_to(new_user_confirmation_path(q: "unconfirmed")))
```

Which is wrong. To fix it, specify only the url instead of a redirection in your `redirect_url` override:

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    if warden_message == :unconfirmed
      # Remove the `redirect_to` call
      new_user_confirmation_path(q: "unconfirmed")
    else
     super
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```